# Raid volumes not recognized Ubuntu 12.04 on HP ENVY dv6

Tags: 12.04, grub2, hp, raid

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP envy dv6 but I get a message every time I boot the system that RAID volumes are not recognized. After a time out of 10 secs the boot continues to grub menu and then boots up normally. I would like to know how can I solve this problem and how can I identify RAID volumes on my Ubuntu.

Comment: You will need to describe your raid configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start with clean disks with no partition table on it or did you reuse the disks. This can be the reason why your system won't boot. Guess how I know.

First clean your disks with:

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/yourdev bs=512 count=1

replace yourdev with the device name of your disks

Then install Ubuntu again. It will then install new gpt partition tables. You only need a swap and a boot partition in raid ofcourse.

Don't forget to adjust your uefi settings in the bios.

Success !